# Calling python from Javascript 404 not found

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to run a simple python script in javascript by using ajax (I would prefer this than using something like Flask).

In my Javascript I have:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "text.py",
    data: { param: "text"}
}).done(function( o ) {
    // do something
});
```

But inside of the browser I receive the error:

> POST http://127.0.0.1:8887/text.py 404 (Not Found)
>   VM119:1 XHR failed loading: POST "http://127.0.0.1:8887/text.py".

My `index.js` and `text.js` are inside of the same directory. When I enter http://127.0.0.1:8887/text.py into my browser the python code is displayed. I'm not sure what is going on.

Any help would be great! Thank you

Comment: in case anyone is wondering, I am using the chrome extension webserver!

Comment: How about changing the ajax type to `GET`? I think your server can't accept  `POST` method.

Answer (score 0):

A simple Flask app will be something like this:

```
/app.py
/templates
    /index.html
```

app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route("/echo", methods=["POST"])
def echo():
    print('echo called')
    data = request.values.get('param', '')
    print(data)
    return data

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8787, debug=True)
```

index.html

```
<html>

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <textarea rows="20" style="width:100%" id="results"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        $().ready(function () {
            console.log('ready');

            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ url_for('echo') }}",
                method: "POST",
                data: { param: "text"}
            }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
                //console.log(data);
                $('#results').val(data);
            });
        });

    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Than run:

```
python app.py
```

Than you would go to: http://127.0.0.1:8787